# How to do <= and >= on sparse matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it possible to do <= or >= operations on Scipy sparse matrices, such that the expression returns True if the operation is true for all corresponding elements? For example, a <= b means that for all corresponding elements (a, b) in matrices (A, B), a <= b? Here's an example to consider:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

np.random.seed(0)
mat = csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10, 12)>0.7, dtype=int)
print(mat.A)
print()

np.random.seed(1)
matb = csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10, 12)>0.7, dtype=int)
print(matb.A)
```

Running this gives the warning: `SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, using <, >, or !=, instead` and gives the error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().`

I'd like to be able to take 2 sparse matrices, A and B, and determine if A <= B for each pair of corresponding elements (a, b) in (A, B). Is this possible? What would the performance of such an operation be?

Comment: `(mat <= matb).A` works for me.

Comment: You're right, that works. Any explanation as to why it's inefficient though, and what a potential workaround would be?

Comment: The problem when the test includes `=`, is that all those 0 values (which aren't stored explicitly) test equal, resulting in many `True` values.  The boolean result will not be sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj Would it be better to test for *in*equality then, and subtract the count == True from the total size?

Comment: `numpy.random.seed` is a callable function, not an object that you set.  Change those to `np.random.seed(1)`, etc.

Comment: ... and rerun your script in a new session, because you have clobbered the function by assigning an integer to the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Pulling some comments together for this answer):

To simply do elementwise <= on two sparse matrices A and B, you can do (A <= B). However, as @hpaulj points out, this is inefficient because any pair of corresponding 0 elements (i.e. (1,1) is 0 in both A and B) will be turned into a 1 with this operation. Assuming both A and B are sparse (mostly 0s), you will destroy their sparsity by making them mostly 1s.

To get around this, consider the following:

```
A = csr_matrix((3, 3))
A[1, 1] = 1
print(A.A)
print()

B = csr_matrix((3, 3))
B[0, 0] = 1
B[1, 1] = 2
print(B.A)

print(not (A > B).count_nonzero())
```

To explain that last line, `A > B` will do the opposite of `A <= B`, so corresponding 0s will remain 0, and any place where `a > b` will become a 1. Therefore, if the resulting matrix has any non-zero elements, it means that there is some (a, b) in (A, B) where a > b. This means that it is *not* the case that A <= B (elementwise).

Comment: Further reading suggests that .count_nonzero is an inefficient operation because it is equivalent to "np.count_nonzero(a.toarray())". It seems like doing (A > B).nnz would be much better. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: The sparse matrix `count_nonzero()` is *equivalent to* `np.count_nonzero(a.toarray())`, but that is not how it is implemented.

Comment: You're right, I'll keep that in the answer. `.nnz` could cause issues if elements have been set to 0

Comment: In the context of NumPy or SciPy, "elementwise <=" would usually be interpreted as performing `<=` on each pair of corresponding elements and collecting the results in an array (or sparse matrix or whatever type), like what `A <= B` does, not as determining whether all of the individual comparisons produce a true result.

Comment: Perhaps this does what you want, but it doesn't do what your question suggests. Your question-answer pair is likely to mislead readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [402]: np.random.seed = 0
     ...: mat = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10, 12)>0.7, dtype=int)
In [403]: mat
Out[403]: 
<10x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 40 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [404]: mat.A
Out[404]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
In [405]: np.random.seed = 1
     ...: matb = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10, 12)>0.7, dtype=int)

In [407]: mat<matb
Out[407]: 
<10x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 27 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [408]: mat>=matb
/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:295: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, using <, >, or !=, instead.
  "using <, >, or !=, instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[408]: 
<10x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 93 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

In your case, neither `mat` or `matb` are particularly sparse, 40 and 36 nonzeros out of a possible 120.  Even so the `mat<matb` results in 27 nonzero (True) values, while the `>=` test results in 93.  Where ever both matrices are 0, the result is True.

It's warning us that using sparse matrices isn't going to save us space or time (compared to dense arrays) if we do this kind of testing.  It's not going to kill us, it just won't be as efficient.

Comment: `np.random.seed` is a function that is to be *called* with the seed as an argument.  It is not a value that is set with assignment.

Comment: So is there a good workaround for doing linear optimization on sparse matrices? E.g. if I need to frequently check Ax <= b, where A, x, and b are all sparse

Comment: I'm not an expert on how the various `scipy` optimizers work, or which ones work well with sparse matrices.

Comment: I'm not trying to use an optimizer because I'm not looking for an optimal solution. However, I need to run that Ax <= b check frequently